# MySQL select distinct with no duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select only unique emails from my list. Here's an example of my database

```
1 john@email.com unpaid newspaper
2 Emily@email.com paid magazine
3 terry@email.com unpaid magazine
4 john@email.com paid magazine
```

the problem is, if I use SELECT DISTINCT WHERE payment=paid, john would appear. When I do payment=unpaid, john would also appear. I only want to select customers with a good payment history (no unpaids). How do I sort that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `sum` with expression `payment = 'unpaid'` to get the emails who don't have any `unpaid` entries

```
select email
from table1
group by email
having (sum(payment = 'unpaid')) = 0
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdb74/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.email = b.email AND b.payment = 'unpaid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `not in` with subselect:

```
select * from `table` where payment='paid' and user not in (select user from `table` where payment='unpaid')
```